# How to clear canvas for all connected clients?

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, socket.io

I'm planning to integrate a whiteboard canvas in my website where users that are connected to NodeJS server through Socket.io can collaboratively draw on the screen. Drawing from one client emits to other clients' screens. For demo purposes I use localhost.

Only problem is that when I integrate a clear function, it only clears from the current user's screen/canvas but not all clients are affected.

I am fairly new and I don't know much about how emitting and broadcasting work but I have tried emitting through socket.emit which passes on a clear function which broadcasts to all clients.

```
<button type="button" onclick="clearCanvas()" id="btnClear">CLEAR</button>

function clearCanvas(){ 
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
socket.emit('clear'), clearCanvas();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to handle the `clear` event.

```
<button type="button" onclick="emitAndCanvas()" id="btnClear">CLEAR</button>

function emitAndCanvas(){ 
   socket.emit('clear');
   clearCanvas();
}

function clearCanvas() {
   context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
}

// this will handle the socket event and clears the canvas
socket.on('clear', clearCanvas);
```

Comment: Where do we add this?